# MySQL : Using a function output with IN

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL function "GetChildren(id)", which returns a comma separated list of ids that are children of the id passed in to the function.

I would like to use the output of that function as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (GetChildren(36))
```

and if id 36 had children ids 37,38 and 39, then I would get those three rows back.

What happens, however, is that I only get the first id.

SQL fiddle seemed to have difficulties with functions, but here is a simplified example that demonstrates the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO test (ID) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);

DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `TestFN` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `TestFN` (GivenID  VARCHAR(1024)) RETURNS varchar(1024) CHARSET latin1
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  RETURN '2,3,4';
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Once setup, if I run `SELECT TestFN(1)`, I get back `2,3,4` as expected.

If I run `SELECT ID FROM test WHERE ID IN (TestFN1)`, I get back just one row, with ID 2. The same happens with `SELECT ID FROM test WHERE ID = (TestFN1)`

Is there a way I can use the output of this function for use as if I had typed the IDs in an `ID IN (...)` clause?

Answer (score 2):

I think MySQL would need to support table-valued functions for you to use one in this way. Otherwise, IN is behaving as expected, `someInt IN (astring)` casts the IN list members to ints, evaluating in your case to `ID IN (2)`

However, you can probably use [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) in a manner similar to what you are trying.

Something like `FIND_IN_SET(ID, GetChildren(36)) > 0`